# Default parameter in all action before action executing in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, onactionexecuting

Is there a way to add some default parameter to every action in MVC application. So I can get the value of the parameter if send from anchor href.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
      int currentformcontrolid = 0;
       foreach (var parameter in filterContext.ActionParameters)
       {
           if (parameter.Key == "FormControlID")
           {
               currentformcontrolid = Int32.Parse(parameter.Value.ToString());
           }
       }
}
```

and my href like this (it's an `AJAX` anchor call) :

```
<a 
  data-ajax="true" 
  data-ajax-method="GET" 
  data-ajax-mode="replace" 
  data-ajax-update="#soapfunction-screens" 
  href="/Patient/Intake?FormContorlID=100003"
  data-islandingpage="False"
  id="InkAlcoholDrug" >
    Alcohol Drug Use 
</a>
```

and my action like (can be any action in the application, every single action should have that parameter `FormControlID`

```
public ActionResult WhatEverAction(int TestID=0)
{

}
```

In `OnActionExecuting` i can only access `TestID` but not the parameter of href that is `FormControlID`

Answer (score 3):

You can access the query string values from the `Request` property of the `HttpContext` property

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    int currentformcontrolid = Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.HttpContext
       .Request.QueryString["FormControlID"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You are right in way. But i i'm sending ajax call. that anchor is sending the ajax call not a page reload call.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about an ajax call, but that not should makes difference if its a query string value.

Comment: yes you saying right. there is nothing in question as ajax call. forgot to mention :| But i need it that way. I tried your solution with ajax call but not getting the querystring value as it is not the page load call. i think it's not possible

Comment: Of course its possible, but we have no idea what your ajax call is.

Comment: am updating the question

Comment: The ajax code you have shown will work fine, except you also have a typo which needs to be corrected - `FormContorlID` is not the same as `FormControlID`

Comment: I have tried but can't get the value when ajax call is sent.  There is nothing even `Request.Form` has no keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172670/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-danish-farhaj).

Comment: You can specify default parameter while specifying route in routeconfig and in defaults you can make it as optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can try specifying that parameter in route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: “Default”,
    url: “{controller}/{action}/{FormControlID}”,
    defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, FormControlID = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I'm going to try this. will let you know if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{

    string FormControlID = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request["FormControlID"];

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right in way. But i i'm sending ajax call. that anchor is sending the ajax call not a page reload call.